# Possible to leave proc_open() enabled on a shared host?

Tags: web-hosting, security, shared-hosting

We are working on a PHP component that requires `proc_open()` for it to work. Because of this, we have trouble running on common shared hosts because `proc_open()` together with other functions like `exec()`, `system()`, `passthru()` and similar are usually disabled.

I am not a sysadmin but what I find interesting is that some hosts actually leave these functions enabled, and I wouldn't say they are amateurish, quite to the contrary from my experience. So the question is:

**Is it possible to make a shared hosting secure with functions like proc_open() enabled?** If so, what's the secret sauce? How can they afford it without risking one user on their servers doing something malicious with the other users' data?

Comment: Welcome to ProWebmasters, please note that cross-posting  question on multiple Stack Exchange sites is not allowed. You cross posted this question with http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92395/how-much-of-a-security-problem-is-phps-proc-open-on-a-shared-host.

@Mods - Please merge with Security Exchange question as per above link if possible.